# loop through an array and add every object to ul as an li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

my end goal is to have this spit out a list of pokemon names to the ul. i can get them to come out on the console but still as an array. 
this is my html

```
<div id="pokeList">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

below is my javascript.

```
pokeHTML() {
    var pokemonList = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pokemonList.length; i++) {
        // console.log(this.pokemonList[i]);
        $("#pokeList ul").append('<li>' + this.pokemonList[i] + '</li>');
    }
    return pokemonList;
}
```

Comment: Your code will work, you just need to make `pokemonList` an array of strings. At the moment it's just a single string, so you're looping through each character.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use "this" in this case
In your function "this" refer to window object, not your javascript function.

So you have to remove "this" or make the "pokemonList" a global variable (remove "var")

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pokeList">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        let pokemonList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
        for (let i = 0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
            $("#pokeList ul").append(`<li>${pokemonList[i]}</li>`);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```